# Rails and ActiveRecord: Save a parent object while using find-or-create on has-many children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying make a complex form (like the railscast) with repeated-auto-complete (modified by [Pat Shaughnessy](http://patshaughnessy.net/repeated_auto_complete))  work for creating articles with many authors (has-many :through).   I've got it working as long as I willing to always create new authors when I save an article.  How can I get my associated author records to only be created when they don't already exist and just get a join table update for when they do?

I know you can you use find-or-create to get this result with the parent object but I need it for the associated objects that are saved when @article.save is called for the article.

in articles.rb

```
before_save :remove_blank_authors
after_update :save_authors

def remove_blank_authors
    authors.delete authors.select{ |author| author.fullname.blank?}
  end


def new_author_attributes=(author_attributes)
    author_attributes.each do |attributes|
      authors.build(attributes)
    end
  end

def existing_author_attributes=(author_attributes)
    authors.reject(&:new_record?).each do |author|
      attributes = author_attributes[author.id.to_s]
      if attributes
        author.attributes = attributes
      else
        author.delete(author)
      end
    end
  end

  def save_authors
    authors.each do |author|
      author.save(false)
    end
  end
```

and the authors partial of my view:

```
<div class="author">
  <% fields_for_author author  do |f| %>

    <%= error_messages_for :author, :object => author %>
    <%= f.label :fullname, "Author Fullname:" %>
    <%= f.text_field_with_auto_complete :author, :fullname, {}, {:method => :get } %>


    <%= link_to_function "remove", "$(this).up('.author').remove()" %>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

I'm using Rails 2.2.2.

The problem is that I can't see where I could use the find-or-create.  At the point where the attributes for the authors are being built - new_author_attributes - I have nothing to search on - that is just pre-building empty objects I think - and at the point where the authors are being saved they are already new objects.  Or am I wrong?

Comment: What does your view and model code look like?

Comment: It's all just boiler plate standard stuff like the example here:  http://patshaughnessy.net/2009/1/30/sample-app-for-auto-complete-on-a-complex-form

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what version of Rails you are using but you should be able to do:

```
 @article.authors.find_or_create_by_article_id(@author)
```

or

```
 @author.articles.find_or_create_by_author_id(@article)
```

then Rails "should" fill in the details for you...

In order to use `find_or_create` you need to have a condition to evaluate it by. That condition (the by_author_id part) can be changed to any column in the Article model.

This is one of the convention features that Rails includes which I haven't been able to find too much info on, so if this is way off, sorry ;)